# Scrolling two divs isolated from another

Tags: html, css

I have two divs inside a fixed position div. Is there a way to make it so that the two divs scroll isolate from another. Like the scrolling of one does not affect the other? I've used `overflow auto` on the children divs and `overflow hidden` on the parent div but that does not seem to work (the scrolling of one div seems to affect another)

Here's the code:

```css
.parent { 
    position: fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
    min-width: 800px 
    min-height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.inner1 { 
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

.inner2 {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

The inner1 and inner2 divs have to have a height of 100%.
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner1">
  </div>
  <div class="inner2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Star Wars?

Answer (score 0):

Setting **overflow** on inner divs to **scroll** instead of **hidden** will give you independent scroll bars. To get the scroll bars to show up you need to set a height for the divs. Currently they are at 100% so no matter how much content they have they will always scale to fit making the scroll bars unnecessary.

Here's an example of how this would work using your code.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKNdBE)

CSS:

```
.parent { 
    position: fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
    min-width: 800px 
    min-height: 400px;
}

.inner1 { 
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
}

.inner2 {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner1">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ut faucibus eros. Duis posuere porttitor sapien, non mollis purus efficitur pretium. Ut dolor diam, cursus sodales condimentum sit amet, porttitor vel diam. Quisque hendrerit massa ut mauris blandit, quis faucibus tortor pellentesque. Duis nulla nunc, bibendum et varius vitae, aliquam sit amet urna. Aliquam sit amet ultrices neque, eu elementum nisl. Cras ac felis ut sapien vestibulum lobortis et efficitur lacus. Etiam a quam a metus condimentum vestibulum. Etiam vel nunc dolor.

Sed eget ex facilisis, dictum lorem iaculis, tempor mi. Pellentesque tempus euismod lacus, at interdum nisi volutpat ac. Proin ornare ultrices massa. Ut in elementum magna, ac aliquet odio. Sed ac augue metus. Aliquam vitae quam dignissim, convallis urna non, pharetra sapien. Vestibulum quis ultrices mi. Cras posuere, ligula et molestie hendrerit, nulla nunc pharetra ligula, dignissim ullamcorper erat tortor vel odio. Quisque porta suscipit ex vel molestie. Morbi feugiat facilisis leo nec ultricies. Proin consequat ultricies erat a egestas. Maecenas in sollicitudin nisl. Curabitur tempor, augue ut fermentum molestie, tellus lorem sodales odio, facilisis dignissim mi lectus faucibus nulla. Etiam cursus id diam imperdiet vulputate.
   </div>
   <div class="inner2">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ut faucibus eros. Duis posuere porttitor sapien, non mollis purus efficitur pretium. Ut dolor diam, cursus sodales condimentum sit amet, porttitor vel diam. Quisque hendrerit massa ut mauris blandit, quis faucibus tortor pellentesque. Duis nulla nunc, bibendum et varius vitae, aliquam sit amet urna. Aliquam sit amet ultrices neque, eu elementum nisl. Cras ac felis ut sapien vestibulum lobortis et efficitur lacus. Etiam a quam a metus condimentum vestibulum. Etiam vel nunc dolor.

Sed eget ex facilisis, dictum lorem iaculis, tempor mi. Pellentesque tempus euismod lacus, at interdum nisi volutpat ac. Proin ornare ultrices massa. Ut in elementum magna, ac aliquet odio. Sed ac augue metus. Aliquam vitae quam dignissim, convallis urna non, pharetra sapien. Vestibulum quis ultrices mi. Cras posuere, ligula et molestie hendrerit, nulla nunc pharetra ligula, dignissim ullamcorper erat tortor vel odio. Quisque porta suscipit ex vel molestie. Morbi feugiat facilisis leo nec ultricies. Proin consequat ultricies erat a egestas. Maecenas in sollicitudin nisl. Curabitur tempor, augue ut fermentum molestie, tellus lorem sodales odio, facilisis dignissim mi lectus faucibus nulla. Etiam cursus id diam imperdiet vulputate.
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is that the inner divs have to have a height of 100%. also does it manner if the inner divs or relatively or absolutely positioned?

Comment: What do you mean by a height of 100%? Do you want both of them to take up 50% of the vertical space on the screen? Yes, both of those have an effect on how they are positioned but depending on the way your code it set up the effect may not be visible.